# how to calculate running total which will reset and recalculate when value exceeds 24 in SQL

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, cumulative-sum

| ID | Value | runningtotal | expected running total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 22 | 24 | 24 |
| 1 | 3 | 25 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 7 |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 12 |
| 1 | 7 | 12 | 19 |
| 1 | 9 | 16 | 28 |
| 1 | 20 | 29 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 22 | 2 |

I was only able to calculate running total but could not calculate how to reset and recalculate running total when it exceeds the threshold of 24 (expected running total column)

Comment: tag your database as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte as (
   select row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.id) r, t.* from tbl t
),
c_sum as (
   select c.id, c.r, c.value, c.value rt from cte c where c.r = 1
   union all
   select c.id, c1.r, c1.value, case when c.rt >= 24 then c1.value else c.rt + c1.value end rt 
   from c_sum c join cte c1 on c1.id = c.id and c.r + 1 = c1.r 
)
select * from c_sum;
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yx_VWAG2)